# How can I fit the missing values with strategy 'mean'?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I can't fit the missing values. I have two columns which has `NaN` Values.

> ValueError: Found array with 0 feature(s) (shape=(537577, 0)) while a
>   minimum of 1 is required.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

veriler = pd.read_csv("BlackFriday.csv")
print(veriler)

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

imputer=Imputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy="mean", axis=0)
pro2=veriler.iloc[:,9:11].values
print(pro2)

imputer=imputer.fit(pro2[:,9:11])
pro2[:,9:11]=imputer.transform(pro2[:,9:11])
print(pro2)
```

Comment: Where did you got the error ?

Answer (score 2):

you already selected the rows you want with iloc
so i think you don't have to use it again in pro2

try changing

```
imputer=imputer.fit(pro2[:,9:11])
pro2[:,9:11]=imputer.transform(pro2[:,9:11])
print(pro2)
```

to

```
imputer=imputer.fit(pro2)
pro2=imputer.transform(pro2)
print(pro2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already done column slicing on `pro2`. Hence don't index again!

Try this!

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

imputer = Imputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy="mean", axis=0)

pro2 = veriler.iloc[:,9:11].values
pro2 = imputer.fit_transform(pro2)
```